# Which of these parameterize the parabola $y^2=x$? $(\sin^2t,\sin t)$, $(\cos^2t,\cos t)$, $(\sec^2t,\sec t)$, $(\tan^2t,\tan t)$

Tags: conic-sections, parametric

In this question

[image: enter link description here]

I tried various different methods to solve it but was ending up with the same answer again and again and unfortunately that answer was not given in the options.

I did my working as shown below

[image: enter link description here]

I somehow believe that my answer is correct because if this is a parametric coordinate it should represent any point on this particular parabola.  Now for eg if we want to represent a point (0,0) we can do that as here $\theta$ would be 90 and hence $cot \theta$ = 0 . This doesn't hold true for the answer given in the answer key which is (D) $tan^2(\theta)$ , $tan \theta$ which becomes not defined at $\theta =90$ . 
But I still could be wrong .
It would be greatly appreciated if somebody guides me through this problem.

Comment: Parametric representations are not unique. Try now to choose the parameter as the angle between $(h,k)$ and the $\color{red}y$-axis, i.e. $\theta_{new}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{your }\theta$.

Comment: I am still confused as to how did you get .\theta_{new}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{my }\theta$.

Comment: Just pick $\theta$ as $\color{red}{\text{the angle with }y\text{-axis}}$ instead and redo your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (I believe) is supposed to be approached like this: we know that a parametric representation for this parabola is obviously $(y^2,y)$ where $y\in{\Bbb R}$. Hence a possible parametrisation (with the change of the parameter $y=f(\theta)$) could be $(f^2(\theta),f(\theta))$ provided that the range of $f$ is $\Bbb R$.

Now look at 4 options and chose that one where the second coordinate ranges over the whole axis. For example, (A) certainly does not work as $y=\sin\theta\in[-1,1]$, which is not $\Bbb R$, so with (A) we get only a part of the parabola, not the whole one, etc

Comment: Yeah but I gave the explanation as to why D can't work.  It does not represent (0,0) then why is it considered as the answer . isn't the whole point of a parametric coordinate to represent all points on the parabola

Comment: @gucci You give the explanation why it does not work **for your choice of the parameter $\theta$**, however the exercise does not tell your that you have to pick it as you did. For example, if you pick $\theta$ as the angle with $y$-axis then everything works fine with $\tan$ (and does not work with $\cot$). The problem with your solution is that you are stuck with this particular choice of the parameter which restricts you too much.

Comment: @gucci Your parametrisation is correct as many others (for example, $(y^2,y)$ as also correct). The problem is that you have to pick a correct one *among just 4 given* and not come up with yet another correct one.

Comment: Oh Ok thanks a lot but I had just one thing to clarify, my answer was also correct ,right? if it was given in the choices

Comment: @gucci Note that the complete parametrisation is supposed to be supplemeted by the range of the parameter. Thus, the answer $(\cot^2\theta,\cot\theta)$, $\theta\in]0,\pi[$ is correct, as well as $(\tan^2\theta,\tan\theta)$, $\theta\in]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$. The main lesson: in your solution you are doing a lot of unnecessary things trying to solve the problem bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

As A.Γ said, the solution is obviously in the form $(f(t)^2, f(t))$.

Let us see if option $A$ works. For the function to be parameterised, then a $t$ must exist for any $k$ in $\sin t = k$. This is to say that if a horizontal line $k$ is drawn, then there must be an intersection between $\sin x$ and $k$ – we are looking for the *range* of the function.

Then the ranges of the following functions are:

$$\sin x \Rightarrow y \in [-1, 1]$$
$$\cos x \Rightarrow y \in [-1, 1]$$
$$\sec x \Rightarrow y \in [-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty]$$
$$\tan x \Rightarrow y \in [-\infty, \infty]$$

Therefore, only $(\tan^2 t, \tan t)$ can parametrise all of $y =x^2$.